# JS: Iterate over page & convert US Dollars to Rands

Tags: javascript, loops, currency-exchange-rates

I have a [client website](http://kasi.promosearch.co.za/members-account-user/?ihc_ap_menu=subscription). Here are test login details **Login**: TestOne, **Password**: password.

I am trying to convert all values on the page into Dollars. I have changed some subscriptions to nominal values (Neo Natal: Month 0-1 & Neo Natal: Month 1-2) to a nominal value to test my function:

```
function callbackTester(callback, cstmClass) {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.setAttribute('src', "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20rate%2Cname%20from%20csv%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.finance.yahoo.com%2Fd%2Fquotes%3Fs%3DUSDZAR%253DX%26f%3Dl1n'%20and%20columns%3D'rate%2Cname'&format=json&callback=parseExchangeRate");
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

function tryMe(cstmClass) {
  var name = data.query.results.row.name;
  var rate = Math.round(parseFloat(data.query.results.row.rate, 10));

  console.log('Rand - Dollar exchange rate: ' + rate);
  var priceConvert = document.getElementsByClassName(cstmClass);

  for (var i=0; i<priceConvert.length; i++) {
    var currentPrice = priceConvert[i].innerHTML;
    priceConvert[i].innerHTML = 'R' + (currentPrice * rate) + '.00';
  }
}

callbackTester(tryMe, 'price-convert');
```

I was trying to use this callback function format in the hopes that the classback function would iterate over the page:

```
function callbackTester (callback, param1, param2) {
    callback (param1, param2);
}

function tryMe (param1, param2) {
    alert (param1 + " and " + param2);
}

callbackTester (tryMe, "hello", "goodbye");
```

But I get the following error:
`ReferenceError: parseExchangeRate is not defined`

...on the function:
`parseExchangeRate({"query":{"count":1,"created":"2017-07-10T14:30:37Z","lang":"en-GB","results":{"row":{"rate":"13.3762","name":"USD/ZAR"}}}});`

I would appreciate any help you could offer!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#How_JSONP_works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your client website has jQuery then you can use it like

```
function callbackTester(callback, cstmClass) {
    jQuery.ajax({
    jsonp: "callback",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20rate%2Cname%20from%20csv%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.finance.yahoo.com%2Fd%2Fquotes%3Fs%3DUSDZAR%253DX%26f%3Dl1n'%20and%20columns%3D'rate%2Cname'&format=json",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        callback(data, cstmClass);
    }
  });
}

function tryMe(data, cstmClass) {
  var name = data.query.results.row.name;
  var rate = Math.round(parseFloat(data.query.results.row.rate, 10));

  console.log('Rand - Dollar exchange rate: ' + rate);
  var priceConvert = document.getElementsByClassName(cstmClass);

  for (var i=0; i<priceConvert.length; i++) {
    var currentPrice = priceConvert[i].innerHTML;
    priceConvert[i].innerHTML = 'R' + (currentPrice * rate) + '.00';
  }
}

callbackTester(tryMe, 'price-convert');
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough! That's some great code right there